# Using start/stopxmlsetups with the ConTeXt Lua Interface

Tags: luatex, context, xml

How could I write something like the following converter using only the Lua interface?

```
\startbuffer[test]
  <html>
    <body>
      <p>Some stuff</p>
      <p>More stuff, with <em>emphasis</em></p>
    </body>
  </html>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:test:*
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{html|body|p|em}{xml:test:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregisterdocumentsetup{testxml}{xml:test:setup}

\startxmlsetups xml:test:html
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:test:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:test:p
  \xmlflush{#1}\endgraf
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:test:em
  {\em\xmlflush{#1}}
\stopxmlsetups

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{testxml}{test}{}
\stoptext
```

I can get the other stuff working with `context.whatever` or `lxml.whatever`; the one thing that is holding me back is the `(start/stop)xmlsetups` command, so I cannot replace, for example,

```
\startxmlsetups xml:test:html
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups
```

with

```
\startluacode
  context.startxmlsetups('xml:test:html')
    lxml.flush('#1')
  context.stopxmlsetups()
\stopluacode
```

I have tried `context.startxmlsetups(xml:test:html)`, `context.delayed.startxmlsetups(xml:test:html)`, `context.nested.startxmlsetups(xml:test:html)`, `function() context.startxmlsetups(xml:test:html) end`, and `function() context.startxmlsetups(xml:test:html) return true end`; they all seem to either do nothing or give errors about `\csname`. The macro definition seems to be in `core-env.mkiv`, but I cannot make sense of it. Is there a way to call these `start/stopxmlsetups` commands from Lua, or to avoid them entirely?

Edit (7/9/18):

I have tried using `#1` and `'#1'` as arguments to a Lua function outside of the `xmlsetups` environment, but they do not seem to mean anything useful there. This works:

```
\startxmlsetups xml:test:html
  \ctxlua{lxml.flush('#1')}
\stopxmlsetups
```

But not `\ctxlua{lxml.flush('#1')}` on its own, or `\ctxlua{lxml.flush(#1)}`, or `\ctxlua{lxml.flush('xml:test:html')}`. Even `\ctxlua{lxml.flush('testxml::2')}` fails to do anything. (`testxml::2` is the result of calling `print('#1')` inside that particular `xmlsetups` environment. Interestingly, outside of that, `print('#1')` gives `##1`; I do not know if it has any significance, but the standard Lua interpreter does not behave that way.)

I also tried the following:

```
\def\setupxmlwith[#xml][#luafunction]%
  {\startxmlsetups{#xml}\xmlfunction{#1}{#luafunction}\endcsname\stopxmlsetups}

\startluacode
  function xml.functions.test()
    lxml.flush('#1')
  end
\stopluacode

\setupxmlwith[xml:test:html][test]
```

Which resulted in:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted

<to be read again>
\stopxmlsetups
\syst_setups_start_xml_indeed ...me \??setup #1:#2
                                              \expandafter \endcsname \e...
```

When I added `\endcsname` before `\stopxmlsetups` in the macro definition, I got `Parameters must be named consecutively`.

Comment: Please add a complete example so any would-be-helper can easily check out your problem.

Comment: Can you just call a lua function with `#1` as an argument?

Comment: @vonbrand This is a MWE even though it might not look like it because it's ConTeXt, not LaTeX.

Comment: @Keiser Put the name of the setups environment in brackets, e.g. `\startxmlsetups [xml:...] ... \stopxmlsetups`.

Comment: @Metafox That works, but the CLD equivalent `context.startxmlsetups({'xml:...'})` does not. It does not give an error; it just doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `\startxmlsetups{#xml}\xmlfunction{##1}{#luafunction}\stopxmlsetups`  You have to double the hashmark of `#1`.